# fadeIn() fadeOut() in jQuery not working in IE but does in FF

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following code that isn't working in IE, any thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login-ad').hide();
    $('.Sub').click(function() {
        $('#login-ad').fadeOut();
        $('#remove-for-login').fadeIn();    
    });

    $('.Home').click(function() {
        $('#login-ad').fadeOut(); 
        $('#remove-for-login').fadeIn();   
    });

    $('.Login').click( function() {
        $('#login-ad').fadeIn();    
        $('#remove-for-login').fadeOut();       
    });

});
</script>


<select>
    <option value="Sub" class="Sub">Sub</option>
    <option value="Home" class="Home">Home</option>
    <option value="Login" class="Login">Login</option>
</select>

<div id="login-ad" >
    This text should fade in when Login is chosen.
</div><!-- /login-ad -->
```

Comment: I was fighting this yesterday and after reading several articles with solutions and trying I've decided to give up and in IE I have no animation.

Comment: @kubal - not an option for me unfortunately.

Comment: is it the fadeIn that does not work, or the click event?

Comment: @Joey - I think it's the click event, because using show() and hide() as replacements for fade works in FF but not in IE as well.

Comment: click is not supported for an option element in IE / Safari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the change event instead:

```
   $("select").change(function() {

         if( $("select option:selected").val() == "login")
              $('#login-ad').fadeIn();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Current release is 1.4.2 perhaps that version has this problem solved. I know IE has some very strange bugs depending on the version - ie rotated images display good in FF and Chrome, but unrotated in IE (gave up on it).

Besides that, you could try to use show("slow") and hide("slow") without the fadeIn and -Out.